# WP Core: Where are terms populated for the admin edit screen?

Tags: core

I am trying to understand how the Admin Tables are populated (for posts, users, plugins...).

With Terms/Taxonomies I am confused. In the  */wp-admin/edit-tags.php* file everything is normal until we reach the `$wp_list_table->prepare_items()` method (where an `$args` is set up to later on go fetch data), but from there on I don't understand where the actual database query takes place.

Looking at the WP Users List Table's `prepare_items()` method, it's quite clear:

```
$wp_user_search = new WP_User_Query($args);
$this->items = $wp_user_search->get_results();
```

So I expected a similar approach for Terms, but looking at the WP Terms List Table class, you can find:

```
public function has_items(){
    // todo: populate $this->items in prepare_items()
    return true;
}
```

Which means that the items are loaded somewhere else. But where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items are loaded via [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) (see [source on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.2/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php#L247)) in the `display_rows_or_placeholder()` method which is called in the `display()` method which is called in `wp-admin/edit-tags.php` (see [source on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.2/src/wp-admin/edit-tags.php#L593)). But the `$items` property is never populated with the terms.

Comment: Thanks Sally, very clear and helpful answer.